# Gradle: configuration injection vs inheritance

Tags: configuration, build, gradle

The Gradle docs state ([49.9](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aproperty_and_method_inheritance)):

> Properties and methods declared in a project are inherited to all its
>   subprojects. This is an alternative to configuration injection. But we
>   think that the model of inheritance does not reflect the problem space
>   of multi-project builds very well. In a future edition of this user
>   guide we might write more about this.

I understand what configuration injection is doing in principle, but I'd like to understand more about the distinctions from inheritance, and why it's a better fit for multi-project builds.

Can anyone give me a few bullets on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer on the Gradle [forums](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/what_is_the_difference_between_inheritance_and_configuration_injection).

Essentially, configuration injection allows you to selectively apply properties to subprojects.